# why evaluate at lambda = 0

Tags: special-relativity

I am trying to understand Herbert Goldstein's introduction to 4-vectors. He describes a 1-D curve in spacetime $ P_(\lambda) $  then he says a 4 vector is defined as the tangent vector to this curve  $$ v = \biggr ( \frac {dP} {d\lambda}\biggr)_{\lambda =0}  $$

why is $ \lambda $=0? what does that have to do with anything? I have been staring at this for like 20 minutes  I still don't understand what he is talking about... it's giving me problems because i need to understand this part later because it is relevant to how tensors transform

  also he says $ \lambda $ is a measure of a length along the curve... i don't really follow that point either... i though $ \lambda $ could be any parameter like proper time etc.

any help on this??

Answer (score 2):

> he says a 4 vector is defined as the tangent vector to this curve

That is *not* true in general. A four-vector is not always defined as the tangent vector to a curve. In the book they are computing a tangent vector to a curve in 3+1D spacetime; the tangent vector is just *one example* of a four-vector.

In particular, the formula given tells you how to compute the tangent vector at a specific point $\mathcal{A}$. Since the curve runs from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ and is parametrized by $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $\lambda = 0$ is the value which corresponds to the point $\mathcal{A}$. So if you're going to define the tangent vector at $\mathcal{A}$, you need to set $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: A four vector is always the tangent vector to some curve. Why do you say no? In fact, this is a popular definition of a vector--- a vector at x is an equivalence class of curves through x which do not separate linearly as the parameter increases.

Comment: In the sense that you can always have a curve (or class of curves) to which any given 4-vector is tangent, then yes. But in many cases it's completely useless as an operational definition, because there's nothing interesting about the curves corresponding to the vector in question.

Comment: thanks david... i'm wondering why the interval is [0.1]? but this is helpful

Comment: You have to pick some interval for the parameter, and $[0,1]$ is just easy to work with.

Comment: this is analgous to choosing a vector with a tail at the origin in 3-d euclidean space?  thx

Comment: I wouldn't say that... in what way are you thinking they are analogous?

Comment: hmm... yeah i guess this is just a mathematical thing you can't really draw a picture

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1704/discussion-between-david-zaslavsky-and-bozostein)

Comment: @David: it's just a mathematics definition, and it's just as good as any other, although considered a little old fasioned for some reason. The question is about a book that uses this definition, so it is not appropriate to say that the definition doesn't work, because it does.

Comment: @Ron: I never said it doesn't work, only that it's not always useful.

Comment: @David: Your first sentence is "that's not true in general" when referencing a vector is tangent to some curve. I don't know what else could be meant by that statment, other than "it is not generally true that a vector is a tangent to a curve". But it is true.

Comment: @Ron It means that the way we generally define vectors is not by the curves they are tangent to. If the quote had been, say, "he says a 4 vector is the tangent vector to a curve," and I had responded with "That's not true in general," then what you're saying would be correct. But the quote from the question is about how the meaning of a particular vector is defined, not just about some properties the vector happens to have.

Comment: @David: When I learned vectors, the source I used defined a vector by the curve that it is tangent to. A vector is defined in this scheme by an equivalence class of differentiable curves. This is the most immediate definition--- it is a formalization of the notion of an infinitesimal neighborhood. It is not popular today, people use differential operators instead, because differential operators are automatically infinitesimal, so you don't need an equivalence relation. But the OP is obviously studying from a source that uses the old fasioned definition (which is fine too).